# Deleted /user/bin/X11 Directory by Mistaken

Tags: 22.04, .desktop

Earlier today, I had some difficulty locating virtualenv for Python ( as a short background), had some difficulty after spent quite some time, while searching for where virtualenv might have been installed.

I came across this X11 folder repeated itself again and again, I was not thinking anything, due to the issue at hand, went ahead and deleted this to **organize** the computer a bit by deleting this self-repeating folder.

boom, lots of file from /usr/bin disappeared, realized something bad had happened.

tried to recover from Trash Folder in Ubuntu, it didn't open

I connected from my previous backups (I hope this helps, I have a habit of running backup every week)

but it's not even opening up in safe mode after reboot.

can someone please tell me what to do?

I have everything in this laptop, this is literally my personal laptop.

Thank you very much in advance!!

This is on Ubuntu desktop (my personal computer)

as far as tags concerned, it didn't provide lots of other tags, not even Ubuntu.

Please don't down-vote this question, gaining point enough to post something is not easy. (Thank you)

Comment: /usr/bin/X11 is just a link to ., /usr/bin and /bin these days. Not much left to run on your system. Save your files and reinstall if you really deleted more than just the link  -- ie the actual contents of /usr/bin.  If just the link was removed, you may just replace it (from an install media if necessary).

Comment: You didn't specify what Ubuntu 22.04 LTS product you're mentioning, but the mention of Xorg implies Desktop to me. You can re-install Ubuntu Desktop releases (including *flavors* using `ubiquity` or `calamares` installer though it's the install script & not installer that does this) without loss of data files, nor your locally saved configs/settings.  Just don't format in the install & a repair install is triggered. You should ensure you have good backups though first.  Switching to text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F4) should still allow login to explore & correct though.

Comment: @ubfan1: Thank you for your reply, currently I installed another Ubuntu 21.10 along side the original partition; currently I only allocated 200Gb for the new one, while the old one still has more than 750Gb allocated to it. worst case I will keep all files, and complete reinstall.

Comment: @guiverc: It is desktop, Ubuntu22.04 LTS  ( StackExchange didn't provide any more right tag, but I could have mentioned ); I can sense if someone is really Linux person should be able to fix my issue if that person was in my situation. But I am not quite there yet, building the system using script, I am willing to spend some time and learn from this process, if there is a book, I would even consider buying it. or if there is a website, please do share. I don't want to have to lose all settings unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: I'm not sure about your last comment, but I may have mislead you sorry with mention of scripts. Ubuntu Desktop ISOs (inc. flavors that use `calamares`) allow a re-install that can be used for repair. You don't need to script (I mentioned script awkwardly in that I feared my prior comment implied `ubiquity` or `calamares` did it; but it's the scripts Ubuntu ISOs include that contain these installers). I'll provide a link to https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/testing-checklist-understanding-the-testcases/2743 where you can search for "*Install using existing partition*" where I talked about it

Comment: That thread I provided was written for QA-testers (*Quality Assurance testers, not end-users*) and I've written about it here too (*numerous times, as others have too*), using that link mostly as its easy to find.  Ensure you have backups first though; and do note it's only QA-tested with Ubuntu repository software, so whilst it may handle some 3rd party; there are no guarantees with 3rd party packages.

Comment: @guiverc: Thank you for detailed explanation!! Really! Since I had so much files in that computer, I really don't want to loose them. I'll wait until I can find some solution to fix this issue